# OpenModelica Simulation Flags Documentation

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

is there any detailed documentation available on what all the options in Simulation Setp > Simulation Flags in OpenModelica do?

OpenModelica documentation does give a short description for some of the flags, but not for all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line run omc.exe +help. It will print all the flags with description text.